# Can I easily switch themes on a fully built website?

Tags: themes, switch-theme

I have a WordPress website for a while now but I wanted to give it a more professional and clean look so I bought the porto theme to make that happen. The problem is that since the website was already completely built, the theme switch kind off messed things up a lot.

I expected this to happen but I have the feeling that I can't really get this right anymore due to a lot of things that apparantly overwrite each other and don't really work together.

What should I do now? Just copy all the text files, then reset the website to default and then start all over or is there an easier way?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Marnix

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is that the more complex your theme is, the harder it will be to replace it with another. Themes should be only about styling your content, nothing more, and everything relating to content itself should be handled in plugins.

Unfortunately, most people think that all themes should come with everything and a kitchen sink, and therefor most themes are not doing styling only, and therefor are hard(er) to replace.

Regarding your current situation, it is hard to say anything concrete without actually understanding the nature of your problems, but yes if you have used in your content a theme specific shortcodes or other kinds of styling, you will need to adjust your content to play nice with a new theme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Absolutely you can switch themes on a fully built website. All data remain same. No need to reset. Before that,

1. Take a backup of your full website with the database.
2. you have to be sure that the theme is download from a verified source like wordpress.org or ThemeForest or template monster. ( Not a null or third-party theme)
3. If your current theme has some custom feature, like custom meta box or any custom functions on theme core after uninstalling the theme you won't be able to access that feature.
4. If your current theme has any plugin (suggested by the theme) then keep active them. No need to deactivated the plugins with the theme.
5. Finally, If you haven't enough experience then hire an experienced developer.